# wpf DataGridTextColumn StringFormat Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I have the following in Application Resource

```
  <clr:String x:Key="DecimalStringFormat">{}{0:n2}</clr:String>
  <clr:String x:Key="DecimalStringFormatN2">N2</clr:String>
```

Now,(Not Working) I have a datagrid text column like this

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  Header="AMOUNT TO USE" Binding="{Binding AmountToUse,StringFormat={StaticResource DecimalStringFormat}}">
```

And this is working fine

```
<DataGridTextColumn  Header="AMOUNT TO USE" Binding="{Binding AmountToUse,StringFormat={StaticResource DecimalStringFormatN2}}">
```

any help why the first statement is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I sort it out.
instead of

```
<clr:String x:Key="DecimalStringFormat">{}{0:n2}</clr:String>
```

i should remove the extra 2 brackets

```
<clr:String x:Key="DecimalStringFormat">{0:n2}</clr:String>
```